# python: get percentage from collection counter

Tags: python, list, collections, counter

I have two lists like the following:

```
l1= ['a','b','c','a','b','c','c','c']
l2= ['f','g','f','f','f','g','f','f']
```

I have tried to get the counts of elements in the first list based on a condition:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([a for a, b in zip(l1, l2) if b == 'f'])
```

the output is:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1})
```

instead of counts, I would like to get their percentage like the following

```
'a': 1, 'c': 0.5, 'b': 0.75
```

I have tried adding `Counter(100/([a for a,b in zip(l1,l2) if b=='f']))`, but I get an error.

Comment: Is  it ok if we first count the elements using ```Counter``` and then use dict comprehension to get the percentage?

Comment: hi, yeah sure.thank you

Comment: Can you share the algorithm? It looks like it is just divided by 100

Comment: Are you sure you want `'a': 0.02, 'c': 0.03, 'b': 0.01` and not `'a': 0.333, 'c': 0.5, 'b': 0.167` or `'a': 33.3, 'c': 50, 'b': 16.7`?

Comment: I think you are right, i actually need the percentage of times each element in l1 equals f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from collections import Counter

l1= ['a','b','c','a','b','c','c','c']
l2= ['f','g','f','f','f','g','f','f']

d=dict(Counter([a for a,b in zip(l1,l2) if b=='f']))

k={i:j/100 for i,j in d.items()}
print(k)
```

To calculate percentage:

```
k={i:(j/l1.count(i)) for i,j in d.items()}
print(k)
```

Comment: sorry, I realized I made a mistake in explaining the desired output

Comment: @zarakolagar, can you explain the algorithm? I can't understand how you go that answer

Comment: sorry, i changed the desired output again. what I would like to happen is to get the percentage of each element in list1 if that equals value 'f' in list2. (e,g there are 4 'c's in list 1 and three times it equals 'f' in list2, so 3/4*100)

Comment: ```Counter``` is already a ```dict```. You don't need to convert it to a ```dict```.

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need it to be done in one line ? If not, maybe this could work:

```
from collections import Counter
l1= ['a','b','c','a','b','c','c','c']
l2= ['f','g','f','f','f','g','f','f']


alpha = Counter([a for a,b in zip(l1,l2) if b=='f'])
for key, item in alpha.items():
    alpha[key] = int(item)/100

print(alpha)
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the frequency of characters in `l1` and perform division to get percentage.

*In your code `b` percentage should be 0.5 and not 0.75*

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','c','c']
l2 = ['f','g','f','f','f','g','f','f']

from collections import Counter
a = Counter(l1)
c = Counter([a for a, b in zip(l1, l2) if b == 'f'])

c = {i:(v/a[i]) for i,v in c.items()}
print(c)
```

```
{'a': 1.0, 'c': 0.75, 'b': 0.50}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but is it possible to get this based on the number of occurrences of each value in l1 separately rather than summing all values? (e,g there are 4 'c's in list 1 and three times it equals 'f' in list2, so 3/4*100, so 0.75 for c)